# Webscraping and sending to my phone via Twilio API

Tags: python, twilio

I'm new to Python web scraping, and I'm trying to send the information I scraped off of barchart.com to my phone (Whatsapp) via Twilio. Here is the code below, how do I execute my idea?

```
//Optionisto.py:name of the scraping file 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from twilio.rest import Client
import requests


source = requests.get('https://www.marketbeat.com/market-data/unusual-call-options-volume/').text

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'html.parser')
#print(soup.prettify())

title = soup.find('title').text.strip()
#print(title)

table = soup.find('table')
#print(table.prettify())
 
account_sid = 'AC4c6710f0a0f0fba4e2d6be2442e228da' 
auth_token = 'REDACTED' 
client = Client(account_sid, auth_token) 
def send_alert():
    message = client.messages.create( 
                              from_='whatsapp:+14155238886',  
                              body='Your appointment is coming up on July 28 at 3PM',      
                              to='whatsapp:+10000000000' 
                          ) 
    print(message.sid)
    for stock in table.find_all('tbody'):
        rows = stock.find_all('tr')
        for row in rows:
            cells = row.find_all('td')
            pira = row.find_all('td')[3].text
            reason = row.find_all('td')[5].text
            #print(pira)
            for transport in cells:
                links = transport.find_all('a', class_ = 'no-underline')
                for identifier in links:
                    ticker = identifier.find('div', class_ = 'ticker-area').text
                    print(' ')
                    print(ticker,pira,reason)

//Clock.py name of the scheduling file
    from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler
from Optionisto import send_alert

sched = BlockingScheduler()

# Schedule job_function to be called every two hours
sched.add_job(send_alert, 'interval', hours=10)

sched.start()
```

So I know how to display what is scraped in output and call the Twilio API, but I don't know how to get the scraped output to be sent to my phone via Twilio.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass in the data you want to send , to your send_alert() function by adding a parameter and replace the hardcoded value of body with the value passed in

Comment: Thanks, but how do I do that, this is my first time with Python.